# How to copy cells to specific position?

Tags: php, sql, excel

I have 2 excel tables. In the first table, I can select all the rows and copy to a specific cell position in the second sheet.

I have some knowledge of PHP and SQL. Can I do this with excel only? Or do I need some script code?

```
Sheet1 (I)
A1, B1, C1 copy to
-------------------
Sheet(II)
IA1 to IIC1
IB1 to IIA1
IC1 to IIB1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP() function in Excel helps to retrieve data from a specific column and place it in the desired column.

Copy A1, B1, C1 column data into of Sheet(II) at D1, E1, F1 then we can write the VLOOKUP() function on Sheet(II) C1 comparing Sheet(II) D1 with Sheet(I)A1.